# how make output "Negative!" at console.log(question4([-1, 4, 7, 11]))

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function question4(angka){
var w=0 , jml=0, rtt=0;
var nilai;
nilai=angka;


for(w=0;w < nilai.length;w++)
{
jml=jml+nilai[w];
}
rtt=jml/nilai.length;
console.log(rtt);
}

console.log(question4([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
console.log(question4([100, 200, 300, 400, 500]));
console.log(question4([-1, 4, 7, 11]));
```

If there is one or more array elements with negative values, then the function is direct
outputs the text 'Negative!'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to call the `question4()` within a `console.log()` because the `question4()` doesn't `return` anything, instead check in the loop `if (nilai[w] < 0) console.log('Negative!')`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this

```
function hasArrayNegativeValue(valueArray){

for(i=0;i < valueArray.length;i++)
   {
     if(valueArray[i] < 0){
       return 'Negative';
      
       }
       
   }
  return null;
}

console.log(hasArrayNegativeValue([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]));
console.log(hasArrayNegativeValue([100, 200, 300, 400, 500]));
console.log(hasArrayNegativeValue([-1, 4, 7, 11]));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it is so easy, question4 function must return a value..

```
    function question4(angka){
        for(w=0;w < angka.length;w++)
        {
          if(angka[w]<0)
            {
              return "Negative";
            }
        }

  return "Posetive";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in array method `.some()`.

```
const hasNegative = [-1, 4, 7, 11].some(elem => elem < 0);
```

The result will be `true`, because this array contains element which is less than 0.

```
const result = hasNegative ? 'Negative' : 'Positive';
```

You can also put this logic into function and return result instead of assigning it to variable.